# Forming array and printing columns/rows in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

I have a homework assignment that is asking me to get 25 random integers (rand()) for a make believe weather station I built. I don't know if what I've done so far is even right nor do I know where to go from here.

I don't just want answers I want to understand how to put the code together. I've searched all over google and in my textbook but it's not making sense to me. I'm not even sure if I can post this type of question here but I figured I would at least try.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{


int get_value()
{
    int ran_num=rand()%40+60;
    return ran_num;
}

int temp_value[25];
int ran_num=0;
for (ran_num=0; ran_num<sizeof(temp_value); ran_num++)
{
    temp_value[0] = ran_num;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use printf with some basic formating ie

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c0\n");
      for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      printf("%0.2d %0.2d %0.2d %0.2d %0.2d %0.2d %0.2d %0.2d %0.2d %0.2d\n",
          i,  
          i + 1,  
          i + 2,  
          i + 3,
          i + 4,
          i + 5,
          i + 6,
          i + 7,
          i + 8,
          i + 9 
          );  
    }   
  }
```

This prints

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c0
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11
03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13
05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14
06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: Ok. So if I only want two columns (sorry, I realize I should have been more specific): one for Time of Day and one for Temperature, I do: 

    printf("c1 c2\n");?

Comment: Try it and see what happens. You said you didn't want the answer so I gave you enough to get moving.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main ()
{
    int temp_value[25];
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(temp_value); i++){
        temp_value[i] = rand()%40+60;
        printf("%d \r\n", temp_value[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should write function separately.
2. One function do one thing.
3. Think about what you're going to do and divide the goal into small procedures.

## code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_value()
{
    int ran_num=rand()%40+60;
    return ran_num;
}

int main ()
{

    int temp_value[25];
    int ran_num=0;
    for (ran_num=0; ran_num<sizeof(temp_value); ran_num++) {
        temp_value[0] = ran_num;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixup process in seven steps. Hopefully, this will give you some insight. It's exactly the sort of thing I would do for my own code.

---

```
// original

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{

    // BUG: this is a "nested" function, which does _not_ exist in C
    int get_value() {
        int ran_num = rand() % 40 + 60;

        return ran_num;
    }

    int temp_value[25];
    int ran_num = 0;

    for (ran_num = 0; ran_num < sizeof(temp_value); ran_num++) {
        temp_value[0] = ran_num;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// moved function to proper level

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_value() {
    int ran_num = rand() % 40 + 60;

    return ran_num;
}

int
main()
{

    int temp_value[25];
    int ran_num = 0;

    // BUG: this _only_ sets all temp_value[0] = 0
    for (ran_num = 0; ran_num < sizeof(temp_value); ran_num++) {
        temp_value[0] = ran_num;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// changed get_value variable name to make things more clear

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_value() {
    int val = rand() % 40 + 60;

    return val;
}

int
main()
{

    int temp_value[25];
    int ran_num = 0;

    // BUG: this _only_ sets all temp_value[0] = 0
    for (ran_num = 0; ran_num < sizeof(temp_value); ran_num++) {
        temp_value[0] = ran_num;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// changed loop to call get_value

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// changed variable name
int get_value() {
    int val = rand() % 40 + 60;

    return val;
}

int
main()
{

    int temp_value[25];
    int ran_num = 0;

    // BUG: this _only_ sets all temp_value[0] to a random value
    for (ran_num = 0; ran_num < sizeof(temp_value); ran_num++) {
        temp_value[0] = get_value();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// changed loop to set all values in array

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// changed variable name
int get_value() {
    int val = rand() % 40 + 60;

    return val;
}

int
main()
{

    int temp_value[25];
    int ran_num = 0;

    // this sets all values, but there is still a bug ...
    // it will overflow temp_value
    for (ran_num = 0; ran_num < sizeof(temp_value); ran_num++) {
        temp_value[ran_num] = get_value();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// changed loop to set all values in array but _not_ overflow

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// changed variable name
int get_value() {
    int val = rand() % 40 + 60;

    return val;
}

int
main()
{

    int temp_value[25];
    int ran_num = 0;

    // now corrected, this sets all values to a random value
    for (ran_num = 0; ran_num < sizeof(temp_value) / sizeof(temp_value[0]);
        ran_num++) {
        temp_value[ran_num] = get_value();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// final cleanup

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// changed variable name
int get_value() {
    int val = rand() % 40 + 60;

    return val;
}

int
main()
{

    int temp_value[25];
    int temp_index;

    // now corrected, this sets all values to a random value
    for (temp_index = 0;
        temp_index < sizeof(temp_value) / sizeof(temp_value[0]);
        temp_index++) {
        temp_value[temp_index] = get_value();
    }

    return 0;
}
```